# How to display a circular list from a calculated index

Tags: python, list, circular-buffer

I have a list of dicts similar to

```
d = [{10: "a"}, {20: "b"}, {30: "c"}]
```

This list is ordered by the keys. I am not attached to the format or data type - I build this list from an external source anyway (this is to say that it can be changed if it helps)

I also have a variable `x` which ranges from `0` to `100`.

What I would like to get is the list `d` rearranged (or rebuilt, or copied somewhere else), starting with the first key larger than `x`. For instance (EDITED, sorry, I made a mistake in the initial example)

- if `x == 2` then `d = [{10: "a"}, {20: "b"}, {30: "c"}]`
- if `x == 12` then `d = [{20: "b"}, {30: "c"}, {10: "a"}]`
- if `x == 22` then `d = [{30: "c"}, {10: "a"}, {20: "b"}]`
- if `x == 32` then `d = [{10: "a"}, {20: "b"}, {30: "c"}]`

I called it "circular" as it represents the "next `len(d)` elements with a `key > x`" in a closed fashion.

I will do this in the form of chained `if`, with the list built manually each time (the cases are covered by the examples above). Apart being an awful solution, it is not exactly scalable if `len(d)` gets large (right now it is `3` so worst case I will go for the chained `if`).

What would be a pythonic solution to handle this?

Comment: Do all of the dictionaries have a single key? Have you considered using `OrderedDict`, or a list of tuples?

Comment: yes, they do have a single and unique key. I did not consider `OrderedDict` or a list of tuples but I can change the data type to whatever is convenient for a solution other than my `if`s.

Comment: All keys in a dictionary are unique, it was the fact that there's only one that surprised me. It would take much more information to determine the best data structure. Your examples don't match the description *"starting with the first key larger than `x`"*.

Comment: what I meant is that there is one key per dict and all these keys are unique (they are timestamps). There are  therefore no cases like `[{10: "a"}, {10: "b"}]`. What I get from the measurements is actually the list I mentioned.

Comment: Ahhh - you are right, I just realized that I made a mistake in my examples. I will correct that right away.

Answer (score 1):

For no particular reason, I wanted to solve this using one list comprehension. Here's what I came up with:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> d = [{10: "a"}, {20: "b"}, {30: "c"}]
>>> for x in (2, 12, 22, 32):
...     [e for i, e in product(range(2), d) 
...      if (0, x) < (i, next(iter(e))) <= (1, x)]
...
[{10: 'a'}, {20: 'b'}, {30: 'c'}]
[{20: 'b'}, {30: 'c'}, {10: 'a'}]
[{30: 'c'}, {10: 'a'}, {20: 'b'}]
[{10: 'a'}, {20: 'b'}, {30: 'c'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use slicing and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for index, subdict in enumerate(d):
    if list(subdict)[0] > x:
        d = d[index:] + d[:index]
        break
```

Is there a better data structure for your needs? Probably, but without more information it is difficult to determine what it would be. As you say the keys in all of your sub-dictionaries are unique within the list, you should look into [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) - you could have all the data within the same single structure.

Answer (score 0):

This gives 30 first when x is 22, since 30 is the first key > 22:

```
d  = [{10: "a"}, {20: "b"}, {30: "c"}]
dd = d * 2 

for x in [2, 12, 22, 32, 42]:
    for i, h in enumerate(dd):
        k, v = h.items()[0]
        if k > x or i >= len(d): break
    print x, dd[i:i+len(d)]
```

*Output:*

```
2 [{10: 'a'}, {20: 'b'}, {30: 'c'}]
12 [{20: 'b'}, {30: 'c'}, {10: 'a'}]
22 [{30: 'c'}, {10: 'a'}, {20: 'b'}]
32 [{10: 'a'}, {20: 'b'}, {30: 'c'}]
42 [{10: 'a'}, {20: 'b'}, {30: 'c'}]
```

But since the list is sorted you can do a binary search for increased performance.

Comment: Thanks - I realized (also thanks to jonrsharpe's comment) that I have made a mistake in my examples

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following, however, this works for simple data formats/types. If your inputs are more complex, then you may need to tweak this a bit.

```
d = [y for y in d if list(y)[0] > x] + [y for y in d if list(y)[0] <= x]
```